# variable was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following code:

```
typename List<Pair>::Iterator Iterator;

int changeTableSize(int newSize, int originalSize){
    List<Pair>* temp = new List<Pair>[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < originalSize; i++){
        for (Iterator j = elements[i].begin(); j != elements[i].end(); j++){
            Pair p = *j;
            temp[p.key % newSize].insert(p);
        }
    }
    delete elements;
    elements = temp;
    return newSize;
}
```

The compiler says that j was not declared in this scope. What can cause this?

(Note that List and Pair are implemented by me)

Comment: What is the type of `elements`? Your question lacks some context.

Comment: Can we have a complete test-case, please.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `typedef` in front of `typename`?

Comment: no, rypename is correct

Answer (score 2):

### The problem.

The statement

```
typename List<Pair>::Iterator Iterator;
```

declares `Iterator` as a variable.

It's no longer a type.

---

### Fix.

Did you mean to write `typedef`, not `typename`?

That would fix the immediate problem, but not future problems of this kind.

To generally avoid such problems, use C++11 `auto` for iterators as loop control variables.

---

### Other comments.

Instead of explicitly using `new` and `delete` to implement a dynamically sized array, consider just using `std::vector`. Much more convenient, safe, etc. etc. Less work, more enjoyable!

Comment: Great explanation/solution.

Answer (score 1):

"Iterator" is it supposed to be a c++ `iterator`? Because if it is, then that's where the problem is. Use Keyword auto for j and it should do it.

The reason it's giving you the error is because iterator is not fully/properly declared/initialized.

remember that iterators are template classes so by that you should inmediately know that it requires at least one template parameter i.e. `forward_list<int>::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Iterator` is not fully defined you may get this error.  Usually you'd see errors about the type being undefined before that though.

Or maybe if you're using an ancient MS compiler.